# How to stop circularprocessindicator on wrong input registration?

Tags: flutter

I'm struggling with a problem on a registration page.
The user can input the fields name, email and password( [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzhuR.png)
If done correctly, an account is made, and the user goes to the landing page. A circularprocessindicator will indicate the time he waits (  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wjfC.png).

The problem is that when a user fills in something wrong and presses the registration button, the process indicator starts en keeps running. The registration button is gone, and there is no way to go forward. How do I stop the process indicator when an error in one of the field occurs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
    class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final _registerFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _nameTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();

  final _focusName = FocusNode();
  final _focusEmail = FocusNode();
  final _focusPassword = FocusNode();

  bool _isProcessing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _focusName.unfocus();
        _focusEmail.unfocus();
        _focusPassword.unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1)),
          title: Text('Registreren',
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1))),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1),
        ),
        body: Center(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
    reverse: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
    child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 120.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(
                          'assets/images/logo.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                Form(
                  key: _registerFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _nameTextController,
                        focusNode: _focusName,
                        validator: (value) => Validator.validateName(
                          name: value,
                        ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1))),
                      hintText: "Naam ouder",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1)),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1))),
                          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _emailTextController,
                        focusNode: _focusEmail,
                        validator: (value) => Validator.validateEmail(
                          email: value,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1))),
                          hintText: "Email adres",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1)),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1))),
                          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _passwordTextController,
                        focusNode: _focusPassword,
                        obscureText: true,
                        validator: (value) => Validator.validatePassword(
                          password: value,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color:Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1))),
                          hintText: "Wachtwoord",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1)),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1))),
                          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                      _isProcessing
                          ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1)),
                                              )
                          : Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                setState(() {
                                  _isProcessing = true;
                                });

                                if (_registerFormKey.currentState!
                                    .validate()) {
                                  User? user = await FireAuth
                                      .registerUsingEmailPassword(
                                    name: _nameTextController.text,
                                    email: _emailTextController.text,
                                    password:
                                    _passwordTextController.text,
                                  );

                                  setState(() {
                                    _isProcessing = false;
                                  });

                                  if (user != null) {
                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            ProfilePage(user: user),
                                      ),
                                      ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                                    );
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Registreren',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 76, 130, 1)),
                              ),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color.fromRGBO(250, 202, 48, 1)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
if (_registerFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    User? user = await FireAuth.registerUsingEmailPassword(
                       name: _nameTextController.text,
                       email: _emailTextController.text,
                       password:_passwordTextController.text,);

    setState(() {
        isProcessing = false;
    });

    if (user != null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                ProfilePage(user: user)),ModalRoute.withName('/'),);
        }
} /// add code in this line
  /// if use input wrong
  /// update UI to show the button again
else {
    setState(() {
        isProcessing = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer should solve your problem OP because the line 
    if (_registerFormKey.currentState!.validate())
means that you are checking if all the fields covered under the form key are valid. So an else condition means not all fields are valid and that there is an error occurring on any of those fields, so setting the isProcessing=false in that else condition would stop the progress indicator from displaying.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work as expected because you have set  `_isProcessing = false;` inside the `if condition`.

You should call `setState(() => _isProcessing = false)` outside of `if (_registerFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

I added this piece of code and now it works. Only thing for me to do is add a snackbar when someone presses registration button and it is a wrong input.

```
else {
    setState(() {
        isProcessing = false;
    });
```